# VMWare Fusion MacOS: VM with static IP while MacOs with DHCP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac, virtual-machine, vmware

I have installed on my Mac VMWare Fusion version 10.

I have 4 different VMs, all of them set with static IPs:

```
VM1: 192.168.0.121
VM2: 192.168.0.122
VM3: 192.168.0.123
VM4: 192.168.0.124
```

At the Mac side, I'm using DHCP.

When I'm at the office, as my LAN works on 192.168.0.* range, any IP the Mac host picks will ping and enable direct connection between any VM and my Mac. All working fine.

The problem is when I go to travel. Every hotel, airport or available WiFi I'm getting on Mac different IP addresses, normally out of 192.168.0.* range. On that situation, I normally have to change the VM static address to those used by the local LAN that I got the WiFi working. Example now: 10.125.131.*

What I need is a way to keep my VMs working within my Mac in the following way:

1. Keep my VMs with static address at the 192.168.0.* range
2. Keep my Mac using DHCP on both cable and WiFi
3. Enable communications between my VMs and my Mac, no matter what WiFi or network address range I'm using
4. Enable Mac to route internet requests from my VMs in a way I can switch it on and off

On Mac, my network settings is AutoDetect. On VM's, I'm using Bridged (autodetect)

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally your problem is that you're trying to use static IP addresses on networks that you don't control.  Whether you're dealing with virtual or physical machines, static IP addresses in general are troublesome to maintain, and your configuration is asking for IP address collisions or other trouble.  There's no avoiding that if you insist on using static IP addresses and bridged networking.

Do you really need to be using bridged networking?  Bridged networking means that your VMs are directly accessible by other machines on whatever network your host is on.  Given that you're traveling, I doubt you want that.  Instead, you should use NAT.  Your VMs will be on a virtual local network and you can assign them whatever IP addresses you want.

Comment: Thanks @jamesdin. No problems on using NAT, but how to seutp the whole configuration? What should be set on VMWare configuration on Mac and on VMs, and how will my Mac route internet requests from my NAT network to the outside word... Please elaborate.

Comment: @Mendes https://communities.vmware.com/thread/569580 might be helpful to you.  I would try to use DHCP reservation instead of using static IP addresses in the guests; it's a lot easier to manage.  As for routing internet requests from within the NAT network to the internet, that should be automatic.